# Why does == work on integers but not on strings?

Tags: java, object, equals, instances

I know this:
When you use == to compare two objects it will compare the two instances of the object and check if they are the equal. 
When you use .equals() it will compare the states of the 2 objects.

Let's say this is my code:

```
String string1 = new String("abc");
String string2 = new String("abc");
Integer integer1 = new Integer(5);
Integer integer2 = new Integer(5);
int int1 = new Integer(6);
int int2 = new Integer(6);

if (string1 == string2)
    System.out.println("The strings are equal");
if (integer1 == integer2)
    System.out.println("The integers are equal");
if (int1 == int2)
    System.out.println("The ints are equal");
```

Why will this code only print "The ints are equal"?

Comment: Everyone on the milky way galaxy, stop asking this question.

Comment: Try it with Integers greater than 127...

Comment: == operator checks for object reference in case of Object such as String, Integer but for primitive it checks for their value. Use `equals` to check for object value equality.

Comment: @MarounMaroun And stop answering it over and over too!

Comment: @whoAmI hit the nail on the head. If you try with Integers greater 127, you have a greater chance of running into the same problem as other reference variables because the objects have a greater chance of not being `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of an object is the memory location which holds the object values, and the value of primitive types is its value itself. If you're using == on objects of type String for example, you are comparing their memory locations.

Comment: Integer is Object and not primitive.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares references because string is an Reference type while `int` is a value type.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in Java strings are objects, and objects will only be equal if their reference is. (They are the same object)

Answer (score 0):

For string, you have to use `equals()` instead of `==` because it is an object.

Comment: *because Java is a bad language that failed to implement the most useful piece of syntactic sugar* - FTFY ;)